# The Microsoft graph endpoints failed with 5xx error randomly. why?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Request URL:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
[image]

Some times when I try to get messages with this query (top > 10) `/v1.0/me/messages?$top=20`, it fails and responds 503-UnknownError. But with this one $top=10, it always works.

Another confusing part is that this problem only occurred with a specific personal-outlook(not organizational) email address!!!

---

There is another similar problem too:

Sometimes, When I try to initiate the graph-client I get this error:

> AADSTS70012: A transient error has occurred. Please try again

---

The other problem:
It's possible to create a new outlook account with valid **Gmail-address**, then you can log in to your outlook account with a username equal to a valid Gmail-address.
This is what I got from M-Graph-Console:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "displayName": "FirstName LastName",
    "surname": "LastName",
    "givenName": "FirstName",
    "id": "286526a26a78f1a8",
    "userPrincipalName": "any-valid-gmail-username@gmail.com",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null
}
```

Check the mail property: it's null !!

- You can not fetch **randomly-genrated-username@outlook.com** from graph-APIs!!
- As I know the only way to find the real outlook email address is to fetch sent messages and parse both of **from** and **sender** properties.

Now you can send an email to any other valid Gmail address from your outlook dashboard, but it's not possible to reply it or send email to your new outlook account address (any-valid-gmail-username@gmail.com).

I'm not sure this is a bug or feature but it does not seem to be a good idea!

Comment: External users and user's without Exchange will always have `"mail": null`. The `mail` property is owned and populated _by_ Exchange so users without a mailbox will not have a mailbox address populated.

Comment: Does the user you've authenticated within Graph Explorer have an Exchange Online mailbox provisioned?

Answer (score 0):

1. 503 is a server side issue. Possibly a bug on the Graph API side. If you are able to reproduce it you should open a support ticket.
2. You should not be able to add a user (in Office365 Business) for an unverified domain. Obviously you won't be able to verify gmail.com as your domain. Therefore, if you have managed to find a scenario where you are able to create an @gmail.com account in Office365, I suggest you report it to Microsoft as a bug (possibly "security" severity).